# compile and link objects with mingw, g++, gcc, ld

Tags: gcc, mingw, ld

I'm following the istructions i found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/zv07M4Gy/) to compile a os kernel.
Unfortunely i get an error and don't know what to do:

```
gcc boot.o kernel.o -T linker.ld -o kern - nostdlib -nodefaultlibs -lgcc
```

yields this:

```
boot.o: In function `start':
boot.asm:(.mbHeader+0xe): undefined reference to `kernel_main'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Everything is the same except that i replaced loader.o with boot.o (it seems to me a mistake, loader.o is not mentioned anywhere on that page).

How can i make it work?

Comment: Probably by renaming  kernel.cpp to kernel.c and compile it with gcc instead of g++

Comment: Searching for a solution i found out the issue is about c++ name mangling. Your solution is kinda realated to this. Solved!

Answer (score 0):

C++ name mangling was calling kernel_main somewhat else.

i defined that function as extern "C" recompiled and than opened the object. I saw the actual function name is _kernal_main. I opened my boot.asm file and referenced to this name.